# Haskell: "instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Random a" and "=> Arbitrary a"

Tags: haskell, random

In Haskell, **Is there a "standard" library/package for generating `Random`/`Arbitrary` enums?**

I wrote the following code, but I can't believe I'm the first person to have this need or solve it (and I'm not certain my solution is totally correct).
Also, I hope that an existing solution has other nice functions alongside it.

Here's a pair of functions to choose a random value from an Enum type:

```
enumRandomR :: (RandomGen g, Enum e) => (e, e) -> g -> (e, g)
enumRandomR  (lo,hi) gen = 
    let (int, gen') = randomR (fromEnum lo, fromEnum hi) gen in (toEnum int, gen')

enumRandom  :: (RandomGen g, Enum e) => g -> (e, g)
enumRandom gen = 
    let (int, gen') = random gen in (toEnum int, gen')
```

and here are instances for `System.Random.Random` and `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Random a where
   random = enumRandom
   randomR = enumRandomR

instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Arbitrary a where
  arbitrary = choose (minBound, maxBound)
```

Here is an example `Bounded`, `Enum` type

```
data Dir = N | E | S | W
   deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)
```

and here is a test of Random/Arbitrary methods

```
> import Test.QuickCheck
> sample (arbitrary:: Gen Dir)
N
E
N
S
N
E
W
N
N
W
W
```

I'm not delighted that my solution relies on these extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}"
```

because:

```
- Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
  in the constraint: Enum a
(Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
```

,

```
- Overlapping instances for Random Int
  arising from a use of `randomR'
Matching instances:
  instance Random Int -- Defined in System.Random
  instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Random a
```

, and

```
- Illegal instance declaration for `Random a'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
```

**Is there a better way? Does my solution fail for some (more "exotic") Bounded Enum types than my simple example?**

Comment: Accepted hammar's answer for giving the workaround. Upvoted all three answers for good advice. Thank you!

Comment: Henning had a similar idea for enumRandom: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2007-December/008725.html

Comment: The use of `FlexibleInstances`, like `FlexibleContexts` and `MultiParamTypeClasses`, is hardly something to be dissatisfied with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard workaround in situations like this is to create a `newtype` wrapper and provide instances for that instead.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}  -- avoid some boilerplate

newtype Enum' a = Enum' a
  deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show)

instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Random (Enum' a) where
  random = enumRandom
  randomR = enumRandomR

instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Arbitrary (Enum' a) where
  arbitrary = choose (minBound, maxBound)
```

Of course, that approach requires some extra wrapping and unwrapping when using the new type, but for use with QuickCheck, that shouldn't be too bad, as you typically only need to pattern match once per property:

```
prop_foo (Enum' x) = ... -- use x as before here
```

Comment: Are you referring to my `enumRandom` or one in a library I overlooked?  And the newtype works around the undesired GHC extensions? Will using the extensions lead to trouble here? The names are scary, but the use seems benign.

Comment: @misterbee: Yes, I'm using the definitions from the question. No extensions are needed for this technique (I'm just using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to generate instances for me; you can always just write those out yourself). As for extensions, `FlexibleInstances` is safe, and the worst thing `UndecidableInstances` can do is to make the type checker loop infinitely if you write something silly like `instance Arbitrary a => Enum a`. `OverlappingInstances` is a bit nastier, but again only at compile time. It's not until you get to `IncoherentInstances` that you can get trouble at run time.

Answer (score 11):

QuickCheck exports a function

```
arbitraryBoundedEnum :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => Gen a
```

This function may reasonably be considered "standard".

Answer (score 7):

It is not safe to declare instances like this for any `Enum` type. The reason for this is that `toEnum . fromEnum` isn't guaranteed to behave like `id`. Take the `Enum` instance for `Double` for instance; the `fromEnum` function simply returns the "truncated" integral value of the double. These "more exotic" types (as you call them) would fail to work with your solution.

This is why it in general is wise to create `Random` instances for concrete types instead, and to avoid general declarations like this completely.

The extensions that you listed are necessarily required if you really want to declare the instance that you declared, though, since it is the signature of the instance declaration itself that requires them.

Comment: Yeah, as I looked at Enum today, I was mildly surprised to learn that Enums are not always Bounded, but it made sense, since Haskell is infinity-friendly with laziness and all. I was more surprised that Double is an instance, and then offended when I saw the definition. These are not your Java's enums!

Answer (score 6):

Another reason not to make your instances "universal": someone who wants to reflect "real world" values more often, and thus wants a custom `Arbitrary` instance with different weightings.

(That said, I've used and defined a helper function for writing that `Arbitrary` instance in my own code just to avoid having to repeat it for every single little type.)

Comment: I read a similar comment on another question (maybe one  of yours)  about different users having different preferences for Arbitrary. But those preferences can vary even within a concrete type, so your concern applies to Arbitrary exports in general, not just the "universal" version. (But I guess the universal version is a much much broader net to cast). I can see why a general purpose library shouldn't users this technique, but we also have OverlappingInstances to the rescue to specializations... I think.

Comment: @misterbee I'm not a fan of things that require using `OverlappingInstances`, as it seems a bit fragile to me; better off not relying on such functionality IMHO.